# Sliderbar with 3 word choices

Tags: javascript, html

Aloha, so I got this idea of adding a slide bar with 3 choices and save it as post, but I don't know how to make both of them, please help me.

I've included a picture of what I'm trying to achieve.:)

[image: Here's a picture of what I'm trying to achieve...]

Thanks a lot:)

Comment: do you have any code to show?

Comment: no if I had I would have done so mate...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use html5's `input type="range"` for the slider and add some positioned strings on top of it. Then you only need to get the value and save it.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/uh4x4wcv/

Comment: Hi k-nut, I have made this code: <form action="location.php" method="post" id="form">  
    <input type="range" min=1 max=3 step=1 name="level" value="span"> 
    <div id="text" name="level"> 
 <span> bad</span>
    <span> ok</span>
    <span> best </span>
   </div> 
     <input type="submit" value="next" id="but"> 
</form>

Comment: Yes this is because the values that the slider has are actually 1,2 and 3. You will have to map those to your ratings on the server.